# Remote Desktop password safety

Tags: windows-7, security, remote-desktop

If I access my computer with Remote Desktop from another computer, is my password stored in any way on that computer? Assume that the client computer is "clean" (no virus, malware, keylogger, etc).

Does Remote Desktop do any caching that could potentially expose my information at a later date (after having logged off and closed Remote Desktop)?

Comment: Your password is not stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this answer by splattne](https://superuser.com/a/6987/156342).

Apparently Windows caches parts of the screen in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Cache`.

To prevent this, disable `Bitmap caching` or `Persistent bitmap caching` (depending on your version of Windows).

This could probably be a potential security risk, if someone else was able to open it and see parts of your screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Passwords are encrypted using win credentials API. It's possible to decrypt them if someone intends to. 
This [**thread**](https://superuser.com/questions/307776/are-saved-remote-desktop-credentials-secure-on-the-local-machine) explains in a bit more detail

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don´t save the password in the .rcp file, one would need physical access to a computer you are currently logged on to crack the password.